# Are default memory allocations in class declaration considered a good practice?

Tags: c++

I have a class the members of which are allocated on heap

```cpp
// client.h

#include <QString>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QWidget>

class Client : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Client(const QString &computerName, int portNumber,
           QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~Client() = default;

// ...

private:
    QTcpSocket *_tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    QTextEdit *_textInfo = new QTextEdit;
    QLineEdit *_textInput = new QLineEdit;
    quint16 _nextBlockSize = 0;
};
```

```cpp
// client.cpp

Client::Client(const QString &computerName, int portNumber, QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    // ...
}
```

I never seen default initialization done this way - whether it was done in the ctor or at the best case in the initialization section of it (e.g. `_tcpSocket(new QTcpSocket(this))`). I can think of multiple reasons against it:

- because we invoke the ctors of the objects we allocate using `new`, we can't use forward declaration now
- seeing these allocations in the class definition might suggest the user that the class has a non-trivial dtor and the objects must be freed when in fact they don't, because Qt will manage them itself
- seeing `this` in `_tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket(this)` is just strange to me

So what's the best way to default assign objects on heap?

Comment: In the case of Qt, it is a common practice that members are forward declared in the header, and they are initialized with `new` in the body of the constructor in the source file. You can declare the destructor as `default` since auto MOC handles deletion, as long as you provide the members `this` as parent.

Comment: @Burak Thanks. Is there any other reason for calling `new` in the body of the ctor instead of the initialization list besides being able to handle 'out of memory' and other exceptions?

Comment: The object is created in both methods. Assigning in the body would only differ in an initial `nullptr` state. So, it does not matter for the machine much. Does it help to the programmer if initializations occur in logically separated code parts? This way, you are less likely to miss calling an `addWidget`, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A default member initialiser that allocates memory is not a bad practice.

<sub>However, not deleting such dynamic allocations in the destructor is a bad practice. Owning bare pointers in the first place are a bad practice. Furthermore, unnecessary dynamic allocation is a bad practice.</sub>
 But that's apparently a problem with the design of Qt.

> we can't use forward declaration now

Sure you can. But I think that you mean that a forward declaration won't be sufficient. That's a good point. If you need to avoid defining those member types, then default member initialisers are not an option in such case.

Comment: When I pass the pointers to the objects I allocated (`QTextEdit`, etc.) to a parent widget in the ctor - it takes the ownership of it. Therefore, deleting in manually in the dtor is undefined behavior

Comment: This is all true, but in the context of this question which uses Qt it may be correct to do so. Qt's ownership scheme predates standard smart pointers and cases such as `QTcpSocket *_tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);` the ownership may be registered via the `this` being passed to the constructor, and the base destructor `~QWidget` may be already taking charge of deleting the instance when the time comes. I'm not familiar enough to be sure about this specific case, but it does happen for some Qt types. But there should be no chance that `QTextEdit *_textInfo = new QTextEdit;` is currect.

Comment: @kenticent `new QTextEdit;` doesn't establish any ownership between `this` and the new instance, it will leak. In your example only `new QTcpSocket(this)` can support this. In any case, this is not good practice in general, it might be acceptable specifically for Qt, but this isn't the case in general.

Answer (score 2):

> I can think of multiple reasons against it:
>
> - because we invoke the ctors of the objects we allocate using `new`, we can't use forward declaration now It is not bad practice, but I would not do it.
>   Why? It introduces dependencies in header files (blocks forward declarations), which forces includes what slows down build time.

This is very big issue. For single source build time difference is not noticeable. If project is big and has hundreds of files it has great impact on build time.

It is even more important to forward declare classes of the project, since small change in one class will lead to cascade of rebuilds over whole project if forward declaration is not used.

I do not see gain to have this done in header and losing forward declaration IMO is big pain, so I would not do it and try force this as a rule in project.

Answer (score 1):

Direct initialisation of class members is available since C++11.

It has some benefits if you have more then one Constructor. All members are initialized with the same values and you don't have to do it in each constructor again (which is a potential source for errors, if you change the init value some time). And its a good way to properly initalize your members and follow the rule of 0.
The initialisation order is exactly as the members are ordered in the class.

In your case, there is no error handling (for new, e.g. "out of memory"), this is a disadvantage. But if you init it in the constructor like

```
Client::Client(const QString &computerName, int portNumber, QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
, _tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket(this)
{}
```

you have no error handling, too.

I personally prefer the direct initialisation, because in combination with the rule of 0 the classes are a lot cleaner.

But you are correct with the forward declaration topic, this is not possbilbe with this approach.

Comment: `, _tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket(this)` in initialization list should not compile.

Comment: I dont understand what this has to do with the rule of 0. I think Qt has some special stuff about lifetime managment of `QObject`s, but that aside, a `new ... ` initializer means that its not a "rule of 0 class", but rather it is managing some resource

Comment: the question was, if default initialisation is bad practice ... 
and yes, if you use new, its technically a no go for rule of 0 ... thats a good reason to use unique_ptr
... but not in combination with Qt ;-)